# How to query this table to output the following?

Tags: sql, plsql

For the below table is it possible to replace the date in 'DL_INC' column for 'PEN' in 'PEN_TYPE' column to the date in 'DL_INC' for 'PIP' in 'PEN_TYPE'? e.g. for MEM_REF 304852 for PEN_TYPE PEN the date should be updated from 06/04/2020 to 11/06/2020. The table is much larger but I've added a small section.

I've tried using merge and insert into with no luck.

| MEM_REF | PEN_TYPE | DL_INC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 304852 | PEN | 06/04/2020 |
| 304582 | MODF | 06/04/2020 |
| 304852 | PIP | 11/06/2020 |
| 403523 | PEN | 06/04/2020 |
| 403523 | MODF | 06/04/2020 |
| 403523 | PIP | 20/07/2020 |
| 503114 | PEN | 11/06/2020 |
| 503114 | PIP | 20/02/2020 |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you an overview of the old dates, and the new dates.

```
SELECT 
   MEM_REF,
   t1.DL_INC as PENdate,
   t2.DL_INC as PIPdate
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.MEM_REF=t1.MEM_REF AND t2.PEN_TYPE='PIP'
WHERE t1.PEN_TYPE='PEN'
```

After this you can use the output of this in an UPDATE query.

P.S.

- You want to change a value of an existing column, so you should not use INSERT. (Because INSERT will add a new record)

Comment: Where has table 2 come from?

Comment: @lostcoder: table 2 is the same table as table 1, and it is used two times in one SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data:

| MEM_REF | PEN_REF | DL_INC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 304852 | PEN | 06-APR-20 |
| 304852 | MODF | 06-APR-20 |
| 304852 | PIP | 11-JUN-20 |
| 403523 | PEN | 06-APR-20 |
| 403523 | MODF | 06-APR-20 |
| 403523 | PIP | 20-JUL-20 |
| 503114 | PEN | 11-JUN-20 |
| 503114 | PIP | 20-FEB-20 |

Update 'PEN' row date with the date from 'PIP' row of the same MEM_REF

```sql
Update A_TBL t
    SET DL_INC = Nvl(( Select Max(DL_INC) From A_TBL Where MEM_REF = t.MEM_REF And PEN_REF = 'PIP'), DL_INC)
Where PEN_REF = 'PEN'
```

Nvl function handles possibility that there is no corresponding  'PIP' row. The value will be updated with itself (no change).
Max function selects max date from 'PIP' rows in case there are more then 1. This handles *ERR Single row subquery returns more than one row*
Data after update:

| MEM_REF | PEN_REF | DL_INC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 304852 | PEN | **11-JUN-20** |
| 304852 | MODF | 06-APR-20 |
| 304852 | PIP | 11-JUN-20 |
| 403523 | PEN | **20-JUL-20** |
| 403523 | MODF | 06-APR-20 |
| 403523 | PIP | 20-JUL-20 |
| 503114 | PEN | **20-FEB-20** |
| 503114 | PIP | 20-FEB-20 |

***Note***: If there are more rows with PEN_REF = 'PEN' for the same MEM_REF - all will be updated with the same date value.
If you need just a Select:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.MEM_REF, t.PEN_REF, t.DL_INC,
    CASE WHEN PEN_REF = 'PEN' THEN
        ( Select Max(DL_INC) From A_TBL Where MEM_REF = t.MEM_REF And PEN_REF = 'PIP') 
    END "DL_INC_PIP"
FROM
  A_TBL t

/*  R e s u l t :  (table data before update)
   MEM_REF PEN_REF DL_INC    DL_INC_PIP
---------- ------- --------- ----------
    304852 PEN     06-APR-20 11-JUN-20  
    304852 MODF    06-APR-20            
    304852 PIP     11-JUN-20            
    403523 PEN     06-APR-20 20-JUL-20  
    403523 MODF    06-APR-20            
    403523 PIP     20-JUL-20            
    503114 PEN     11-JUN-20 20-FEB-20  
    503114 PIP     20-FEB-20          
*/
```

Regards...